# ValueError("Cannot convert {0!r} to Excel".format(value)) on trying to write data into excel cell using python code

Tags: python

```
reporting_date = "select distinct(reporting_date_id) from tablename"
HiveDF = hc.sql(reporting_date) 
getreporting_date=HiveDF.toPandas() 
Rep_period_val= 'Reporting Period: ' + getreporting_date.astype(str) 


import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb2 = load_workbook('filename.xlsx')
sheet=wb2["Slide 2-Tier1"]

sheet.cell(row =1,column=1).value = Rep_period_val
```

I am getting error as below , not able to write to excel

ValueError: Cannot convert               reporting_date_id
0  Reporting Period: 2023-04-30 to Excel